# Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _arrays2.default) is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I got following behavior if i import SearchArea.js in Index.js

**SearchArea.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import SearchAreaClasses from './SearchArea.css';

class SearchArea extends Component {
    state = {
        showFederalState: false
    };

    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                <div className={SearchAreaClasses.SearchBarContainer}>
                    <div className={SearchAreaClasses.SearchBarContent}>

                        <div className={SearchAreaClasses.SearchBarColumn}>
                            <div className={SearchAreaClasses.SearchBarColumnLabel}>Federal State</div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default SearchArea;
```

**Index.js**

```
import SearchArea from './SearchArea/SearchArea';
...
render() {
  return(
    <SearchArea />
  )
}
```

I got following error on the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _arrays2.default) is not a function
    at new SearchArea (SearchArea.js?eda9:4)
```

But when i remove from SearchArea.js the defined state,

```
state = {
        showFederalState: false
};
```

it work's like a charm.

---

React v 16.1.1

Google Chrome 64.0.3282.119

Mac OS 10.13.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try initializing the state using the recommended `constructor` method by the react team.

```
class SearchArea extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)    
    this.state = {
      showFederalState: false
    };
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a constructor to the SearchArea class. I had a similar problem a few days ago and that fixed it. Through I got a different error message, so don't take my word for it.